# Texture packer size issue in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am making texture packer in Libgdx in which If I take the size of packer 2,048 * 2,048 which make only one packer image of size 3.14 Mb and If I take the size of packer 1,024 * 1,024 then it makes four packer image and all four packer image total size is 2.94 Mb. Which size of packer I should prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer 1024*1024

Pros:

This image resolution can be loaded in ldpi phones like Samsung Galaxy Y.

2048*2048 will take 16 MB of graphics memory

while 1024*1024 will take 4MB

so i think u can go with 1024*1024

Also i would like to suggest u that if u are using images with no alpha value importance ( Backgrounds) you can later covert .png to .jpg and edit your pack file with image name .png to .jpg.

Hope it helps u